# Auto-property default value

Tags: c#, default, automatic-properties

Can I generate in C# auto-property with default value?

```
public class MyClass
{
     MyClass()
     {
         Reason = "my reason";
     }

     public string Reason{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it to see if it works?

Comment: Are you asking if the code you've provided is valid or if there is another way ? For auto-properties - NO, that's the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but to be able to create an instance from outside your class, make your constructor public.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Reason = "my reason";
    }

    public string Reason {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Definitely. Just like you've shown it.

Comment: What's the downvote for? (I originally wanted to post a single "Yes.", but unfortunately, SO wouldn't let me post such a short answer.)

Comment: Didn't put the down-vote but it won't work `as shown` because the constructor is not public, so `var mc = new MyClass()` won't even compile.

Comment: @Abbas: As explained on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx), the default visibility for members is `private`, so indeed the constructor is not public. It can only be called from within the class. Where does the OP require `var mc = new MyClass();` to be compileable?

Comment: @Abbas He's not doing `new` anywhere ... If you want to be pedantic. Anyway +1 :)

Comment: Didn't say he requires this, I was just mentioning this. But you're right in your answer and @DimitarDimitrov, didn't mean to be pedantic, I merely tried to help, +1 from me too. :)

Comment: @Abbas Sure I get it, sorry if I sounded like a jerk, had a long day :) Cheers

Comment: No it's good to point it out. Makes me think longer before giving comments/answers. ;)

Comment: @Abbas: Just to be clear; it's true that a public constructor is probably desirable. But it does compile as is, and maybe the OP wants to keep the constructor private and add a static factory method instead (or just instantiate the class via reflection for some instance).

Comment: You're absolutely right. That's why I explained you were right from the beginning and why you got the upvote from me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a default constructor and initialize the autoproperty value.

Comment: That's what he did. He just wants to know if it'll work.

Comment: I am asking if it is a correct/best way

Comment: Yes, that's the only way.!!

Comment: I proposed this solution because it works! ;)